# Django Many-to-Many related_name

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M63m4.png)

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user              = models.OneToOneField(User)
    followers         = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='is_following', blank=True) 
    activation_key    = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    activated         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

in shell when I type `User.profile.followers.all()` and when i type `User.is_following.all()` I receive different result.

Comment: [See doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: sorry for not properly made question. Click on image. And read question. I don't know how to edit.

Comment: I read it 10 times i tried try to find solution in source code but i failed. I understand how it works with ForeignKey. But it works differently with MtM. I am not that kind of person who ask 2500 question here. It is my first question.

Comment: When i type User.profile.followers.all() i am through onetoone field get profile associated with my user and then i get all followers connected to this profile. But when i use related name it gives me different result. When i use related_name on foreignkey i skip part of model_set. But in MtM working differently.

Comment: Well if somebody is following you, then you are *not* per se following him/her. The relation works "directional".

Comment: But when i type User.profile.followers.all() i am  querying followers associated with certain profile associated with certain user. And when i do User.is_following.all() i do exact same query( i a m just using related name) . But result not the same. ))))

Comment: @Ivan nope you are NOT doing the "exact same query".

Comment: could you explain to me please what query i do in  User.is_following.all() It is most brain breaking part in my Django experience)

Comment: By the way, you should not have a MtM field here, it's supposed to be a foreign key (if i understood what you wanted to do with that model)

Comment: @Ivan this is nothing Django-specific, just plain relational m2m stuff.  Look at your m2m table, then at the SQL queries generated by both `.followers.all()` and `.is_following.all()` (nb: use `print(User.profile.followers.all().query)` to see the SQL query)

Answer (score 1):

First, i'd change :

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(User
```

to

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(Profile
```

Then, if you try to print

```
 user1 = Profile.objects.create() #missing args but you don't need it for the example
 user2 = Profile.objects.create()
 user1.followers.add(user2)
 user1.followers.all()
```

You'll get :

```
[user2]
```

But if you do

```
 user1.is_following.all()
```

You'll get :

```
[]
```

Finally, if you do :

```
user2.is_following.all()
```

Result will be :

```
[user1]
```

related_name allows you to get your object in another object.

Comment: Thanks for response. I understand it. But in documentation said that related_name for ForeignKey is the same for ManyToManyfield. When i want to get objects connected to instance in Foreignkey field i use model_set but in MTM it is not the same.

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model()
>>> Ivan = User.objects.last()
>>> Ivan.profile.followers.all()
<QuerySet [<User: johnny>, <User: qwe>, <User: saao>]>
>>> Ivan.is_following.all()
<QuerySet [<Profile: qwe>]>
>>>

Comment: I understand that i don't understand something in MTM field

Comment: You should take a look at [one to many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [many to many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) docs. Django doc is really well done.

Comment: I understand how oto mtm otm works. But i don't understand why related_name  works not the same way it works with foreignkey https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/ I made this project for testing. I made specially to try it my way. Why related_name(or model_set) with foreignkey return all objects connected to some instance but in MTM not the same way.

Comment: Oh ok. Well you've an object 'A'. 'A 'has as fk object 'B'. 'A.B' will show you B. But what if you want all objects which has 'B' as fk ?

Comment: Then you put a related name in 'A's foreign key.

Comment: @Ivan: it works exactly the same way as a foreign key.